# Why can't I use operator bool() for std::ofstream

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Why can't I write the following code?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool touch(const std::string& file_path)
{
    return std::ofstream(file_path, std::ios_base::app);
}

int main()
{
    touch("foo.txt");
}
```

**Output**

```
prog.cpp: In function 'bool touch(const string&)':
prog.cpp:6:52: error: cannot convert 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' to 'bool' in return
  return std::ofstream(file_path, std::ios_base::app);
```

http://ideone.com/IhaRaD

I know that `std::fstream`'s `operator bool()` defined as `explicit` but I don't see any reason why it should fail in such case. There's no intermediate conversion, just the temporary `std::ofstream` object and `bool`. What's the reason?

Comment: As the operator is explicit and there is no context to convert to bool implicitly then you have to convert to bool explicitly.:)

Comment: Explicit makes it not convert to bool unless you directly invoke cast.

Comment: `return !!` works here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's **exactly because** `operator bool()` is defined as `explicit` that you can't use it in this way.  The only context where an `explicit operator bool()` is automatically invoked is for unambiguous conditionals, such as `if` `while`, `?:`, `!` and the middle expression of `for`.  (For a more complete summary, see my question [When can I use explicit `operator bool` without a cast?](/q/39995573)).

A `return` statement's value is never *contextually converted to `bool`*, so if you want to convert `std::ofstream` to `bool` as a return value, you *must* use `static_cast<bool>()` or equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

As the operator is declared like explicit and there is no context that allows implicit converting to bool (as for example using in the if statement) then you have to convert the expression with the stream to `bool` explicitly.
For example

```
bool touch(const std::string& file_path)
{
    return bool( std::ofstream(file_path, std::ios_base::app) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `operator bool` looks like this:

```
explicit operator bool() {/*...*/}
```

Note the use of explicit here, this means there is no auto casting from class to bool. That means for your code, you have to do this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool touch(const std::string& file_path)
{
    return static_cast<bool>(std::ofstream(file_path, std::ios_base::app));
}

int main()
{
    touch("foo.txt");
}
```

No matter what, a cast is required (preferably `static_cast<bool>`), because of implicit conversion being dangerous.